Facing error while encrypting password in nodejs and showing it to workbench mysql
I'm currently developing a password manager application using Node.js and React. I'm facing an issue with encryption and decryption functionality using the AES-256-CTR algorithm. Whenever I attempt to encrypt passwords on the backend using Node.js's crypto module, I encounter a "TypeError: Invalid initialization vector" error
when i commenting the part
const encryptedData = encrypt(password); console.log(encryptedData);
it is running fine in mysql workbench. all three column are working fine just iv section as "jojo"
index.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql2");
const cors = require("cors");
const { encrypt } = require("./EncyrptionHandler");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const PORT = 3001;
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "root",
  host: "localhost",
  password: "root",
  database: "passwordmanager",
});

db.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("Connected");
});
app.post("/addpassword", (req, res) => {
  const { password, website } = req.body;
  // const { iv, password: encryptedPassword } = encrypt(password);
  // console.log(iv, password);
  const iv = "jojo";
  const encryptedData = encrypt(password);
  console.log(encryptedData);
  const query = "INSERT INTO password (password, website, iv) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
  db.query(query, [password, website, iv], (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error inserting data:", err);
      res.status(500).send("Error inserting data");
      return;
    }
    res.send("Success");
  });
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("<h1>hello world</h1>");
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("listening on port");
});


EncryptionHandler.js
const crypto = require("crypto");

const secret = "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis";

const encrypt = (password) => {
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16); // Generate a 16-byte IV for aes-256-ctr
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-ctr", Buffer.from(secret), iv);
  let encryptedPassword = cipher.update(password, "utf8", "hex");
  encryptedPassword += cipher.final("hex");

  return {
    iv: iv.toString("hex"),
    password: encryptedPassword,
  };
};

module.exports = { encrypt };


App.js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [website, setWebsite] = useState("");

  const addPassword = () => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/addpassword", {
      password: password,
      website: website,
    });
  };

  // console.log(password);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="AdddingPassword">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Ex. 123456"
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="facebook.com"
          onChange={(e) => setWebsite(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={addPassword}>Add Password</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


Error
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I have also tried writing async await in addpassword
const addPassword = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/addpassword", {
        password: password,
        website: website,
      });
      console.log("Password added successfully:", response.data);
      // Optionally, clear input fields or provide feedback to user
      setPassword("");
      setWebsite("");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error adding password:", error);
      // Optionally, handle specific error cases
    }
  };```
still facing error
[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/CUvWcj2r.png
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/KnenAbWG.png


Reduce this to an MRE. That'll help you debug it too.

(BTW, the error I get from your encrypt is RangeError: Invalid key length...)

As AKX already mentions the error originates from an invalid key length. AES-256 expects a key of length 256bits/32bytes but your key is 45 bytes long.
